# including keyclocak group IDs in token

Tags: token, keycloak

I am new to keyclocak. I have group assignments for users, and I was able to enable a group mapper, which puts groups (names only) in the token returned to a client. In my app, I need to associate data with groups, so I'd like for a way to add group IDs to the token.

Is there a way I can add the group ID to the token? Or, can my app query for group ids/names without having to have admin credentials on keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom protocol mapper:

```
package org.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.keycloak.models.ClientSessionContext;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.ProtocolMapperModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserSessionModel;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAccessTokenMapper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAttributeMapperHelper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCIDTokenMapper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.UserInfoTokenMapper;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderConfigProperty;
import org.keycloak.representations.IDToken;

public class GroupIdProtocolMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper implements OIDCAccessTokenMapper, OIDCIDTokenMapper, UserInfoTokenMapper {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "group-id-protocol-mapper";

    private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.addTokenClaimNameConfig(configProperties);
        OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.addIncludeInTokensConfig(configProperties, GroupIdProtocolMapper.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayCategory() {
        return TOKEN_MAPPER_CATEGORY;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return "Group Id";
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "Map user group id to a token claim.";
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return configProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setClaim(IDToken token, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel, UserSessionModel userSession, KeycloakSession keycloakSession,
                            ClientSessionContext clientSessionCtx) {

        List<String> groups = (List)userSession.getUser().getGroupsStream().map((g) -> {
            return g.getId();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        String protocolClaim = (String)mappingModel.getConfig().get("claim.name");

        OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.mapClaim(token, mappingModel, groups);
    }
}
```